# Convert Excel table to 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, phpexcel

I have next Excel table with date in first column and some data in others (B, C).

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

And I want to transform it to table like on pic 3:
[image]

To do this you need to add up the data from each row and column within an hour (don't know how to say it right) and multiply by 2400.
For example, from first picture we have (0.0022 + 0.0078 + 0.0021 + 0.0078) * 2400 ≈ 47 — first element of the table from third picture.

I'm trying to do it with PHPExcel library:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("data.xlsx");
$highestRow  = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
$day = 1;
$hour = 1;
$data = array(array());
for ($i = 1; $i < $highestRow + 1; $i++) {
    $cell1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $i)->getValue();
    $cell2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $i)->getValue();
    $data[$day][$hour] += $cell1 + $cell2;
    if($i % 2 == 0)  { $data[$day][$hour] *= 2400; $hour++; }
    if($i % 48 == 0) $day++;
    if($hour % 24 == 0) $hour = 1;
}
```

But instead of working code I get errors
[image]

Line 22:

```
$data[$day][$hour] += $cell1 + $cell2;
```

I think that something with my 2D array and as I can see my array keys is bad (not 1-24 for hours).

What should be the code to get my data in 2D array like `$data[1..29-31][1-24]` or any other? Or may be it is possible to get table from picture #3 some other way?

Comment: *related:* The fact that A1:A1487 is left-aligned and A1488 is right-aligned concerns me. Left-alignment in a cell typically indicates text; in this case a text representation of a datetime. If those were true datetimes they would all be right-aligned by default.

Comment: Which one is the line no 22?

Comment: @Jeeped it's not important. I can count number of days like $highestRow/48.

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD I don't understand the question.

Comment: As you see the error message, it's coming from line number 22. So just wanted to know which line from above codes is line no 22.

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD Sorry.  This line $data[$day][$hour] += $cell1 + $cell2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your line number 22 is

```
$data[$day][$hour] += $cell1 + $cell2;
```

You are trying to increment `$data[$day][$hour]` which is not even defined yet. You need to define it before trying to increment it. I am not sure, it will make the sheet work like you are expecting. But this will fix the error you are getting. (Add this before line 22)

```
if(!isset($data[$day])) {
    $data[$day] = array(); //Setting the day which will get the hours in array
}
if(!isset($data[$day][$hour])) {
    $data[$day][$hour] = 0; //Setting the hours which will contain the incremented values for each hour. Setting it 0, the next code blocks will increment it. 
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, it seems. Notifications really appeared due not declared array and I had minor mistake with hour detection. Instead of
 if($hour % 24 == 0) $hour = 1; 
shoud be:
if($hour % 25 == 0) $hour = 1;
Thanks @TaReQ MahMooD.